# How do I write and structure code in most efficient way possible?

Tags: python, performance, structure

Few weeks ago I needed a crawler for data collection and sorting so I started learning python.
Same day I wrote a simple crawler but the code looked ugly as hell. Mainly because I don't know how to do certain things and I don't know how to properly google them.
Example:
Instead of deleting [, ] and ' in one line I did

```
extra_nr = extra_nr.replace("'", '')
extra_nr = extra_nr.replace("[", '')
extra_nr = extra_nr.replace("]", '')
extra_nr = extra_nr.replace(",", '')
```

Because I couldn't do stuff to list object and when I did str(list object) It looked like ['this', 'and this'].
Now I'm creating discord bot that will upload data that I feed to it to google spreadsheet. The code is long and ugly. And it takes like 2-3 secs to start the bot (idk if this is normal, I think the more I write the more time it takes to start it which makes me think that code is garbage). Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

**My question is** how do I know that I wrote something good? And if I just keep adding stuff like in the example, how will it affect my program? If I have a really long code do I split it and call the parts of it only when they are needed or how does it work?

Comment: Code like that doesn't take very long, but if there are a lot of them, you might do better with a regular expression.  `import re` / ` extra_nr = re.sub( r"['\[\],]", '', extra_nr )`

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr to get good at Python and write good code, write a lot of Python and read other people's code. Learn multiple approaches to different problem types and get a feel for which to use and when. It's something that comes over time with a lot of practice. As far as resources, I highly recommend the book "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python".

As for your code sample, you could use `translate` for this:

```py
def strip(my_string):
    bad_chars = [*"[],'"]
    return my_string.translate({ord(c): None for c in bad_chars})
```

`translate` does a character by character translation of the string given a translation table, so you create a small translation table with the characters you don't want set to `None`.

The list of characters you don't want is created by unpacking (splatting) a string of the characters.

```py
>>> [*"abc"] == ["a", "b", "c"]
True
```

Another option would be using comprehensions:

```
def strip(my_string):
    bad_chars = [*"[],'"]
    return "".join(c for c in my_string if c not in bad_chars)
```

Here we use the comprehension format `[x for x in y]` to build a new list of `x`s from `y`, just specifying to drop the character if it appears in `bad_chars`. We then join the remaining list of characters into a string that doesn't have the specified characters in it.

Comment: A lot of people recommended that book. I just ordered it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely improve quickly from reading (or listening) up on Python best practices from resources like [Real Python](https://realpython.com/) and [Talk Python To Me](https://talkpython.fm/).

Meanwhile, I'd recommend starting using some code analysers like [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) and [bandit](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as part of your regular workflow.

In any case, welcome to the world of Python and enjoy! :-)

Comment: Thank you! The dopamine rush when something you write works is amazing :) Do you have any video suggestions? Like a playlist or a channel on youtube?

Answer (score 0):

You can use maketrans() to define characters to remove (3rd parameter):

```
def clean(S): return S.translate(str.maketrans("","","[],'"))

clean("A['23']") # 'A23'
```